# am unable to sync the playlist with the audio player

Tags: android, react-native, expo

hey am trying to make an app that plays an offline playlist, i have a scrollView with views that hold the tracks and i put them in an array called PlaylistElements[] , am having trouble getting the position of clicked track View, it's really important as i'm using it as the index that gets the name and the file path of the audio file.

NOTE: i've tried giving each track element an index value, but it dosn't work since am pushing these track elements into an array using a for loop

```
 for (i = 0; i < PlayList.length; i++) {

      if(i%5 !== 0){
            let addTrackElement = PlaylistElements;
            console.log(PlaylistElements.length + "  " + i)
            //console.log(this.props.children)
           // console.log(PlaylistElements[i].type.render.length)
           // this.position = i;
     // console.log(styles.playlistElementContainer)
      addTrackElement.push(

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.playlistElementContainer}
                           activeOpacity={0.9}
                           //ref={()=>{i}}

                           onPress={()=>{
                            if (this.playbackInstance != null) {
                              this.index = i;
                              this
                              .playbackInstance
                              .pauseAsync();
                              this._loadNewPlaybackInstance(this.state.shouldPlay);
                            }else if(this.playbackInstance === null){
                              this._loadNewPlaybackInstance(this.state.shouldPlay);
                            }
                            }}

                           >

                          <Image
                          style={{width: 40,
                                  height: 40,
                                  borderWidth : 1,
                                  borderRadius: 5,
                                 // flex : 1,
                                  marginRight: 5,
                                  marginLeft: 5,
                                  borderColor : 'black',}}
                          source={require('./assets/Images/reactIcon.png')}
                          />
                        <View>
                          <Text 
                          style={{//borderWidth: 2,
                                    lineHeight: 20,
                                    //color: 'white'
                                 }}>

                          { PlayList[i].name}
                          </Text> 
                          <Divider style={{ height : 1,
                                            backgroundColor: '#383838',
                                             }} />
                           <Text 
                           style={{//borderWidth: 2,
                                   lineHeight: 20}}>
                           testttttttttttttttttttttt
                           </Text> 
                            </View>
                      </TouchableOpacity>

                    );
                   }else if(i%5 === 0){
                      let addTrackElement = PlaylistElements;
                      console.log(PlaylistElements.length + "  " + i)
                      // console.log(styles.playlistElementContainer)
                       addTrackElement.push(
                         <View style={styles.adSpace}>        

                         </View>
                       );
                    }


                }
```

NOTE2 : i also tried to give add an event listner to PlaylistElements[] then map the clicked track, but it gives this error : " item.addeventlistner is not a function".

down is it's code i call inside componentdidmount() :

```
  getPosition(){
    //first store array in a variable
let container = [...PlaylistElements];

//loop through array with forEach function
container.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(container.indexOf(item));
    });
});

  }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiDjj.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  this.index = i;
```

this.index indise a loop will get always the latest value, because you are overwriting the same variable every iteration of the loop.

what you can do is to create a separate method to play and call it with the index as a parameter.

```js
class Playlist extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.playTrack = this.playTrack.bind(this);
  }

  playTrack(index) {
    console.log(`you should play track ${i}`);
  }

  render() {
    return {
         // your loop thing
         // and your component,
         // but the important bit is 
           onPress={() => {
             this.playTrack(i);
           }

    }
  }
```

Because you mention in comments that you code is messy at this point, I've created a simpler example where you can see the simple pattern.

https://gist.github.com/alfonsodev/4efa70aa382c481259cb777dee85fdac

Comment: yea i know that the i causes an issue inside  a for loop , hence the getPosition() methode, but i keep getting that error " item.addeventlistner is not a function". any idea on why that happens, also i can link the whole js file,  it's messy but i can guid you through it !!

Comment: what I mean is that you don't need getPosition() , 
you can make the code simpler if on onPress you want to play a track, then you should have a playTrack method you can pass the position i from TouchableOpacity 
onPress to playTrack method.
The `item.addeventlistner` it's an unnecessary complication. 
But if you wanna know react-native doesn't provide the same methods than React web, so in this case, the components don't have addEventListener

Comment: I've created an example where you can see the pattern working 
https://gist.github.com/alfonsodev/4efa70aa382c481259cb777dee85fdac
and I've updated the answer with the link

Comment: okay, but still how can i recover the i value of the clicked touchableOpacity since it is inside a for loop and by the time I trigger the onPress methode the (i) would have reached it's last value

Comment: okay, i understand what you did , so i was trying to solve this problem the wrong way , thanks very much, am going to implement now :)

Comment: no problem, sometimes when code gets messy is useful to isolate the problem in a simpler example, remember to mark the question as solved so future users know that it worked and good luck!